# Firebase Hosting / Functions vs Zeit Now

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js, vercel

I have a next.js Server side rendered application. hosted in Zeit now and Firebase Hosting / Functions, the same app.
Google insight gives different performance analysis,

**Firebase** 
*Mobile* : 20
*Desktop* : 40

**Now.sh** 
*Mobile* : 60
*Desktop* : 80

can someone explain this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [ZEIT Now](https://zeit.co/) is made by the creators of Next.js and has first-class support for Next.js. When you deploy your Next.js app to ZEIT Now, the following happens by default:

  - Pages that use Static Generation and assets (JS, CSS, images, fonts, etc) will automatically be served from the [ZEIT Now Smart CDN](https://zeit.co/smart-cdn), which is blazingly fast.
  - Pages that use Server-Side Rendering and API routes will automatically become isolated [Serverless Functions](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/serverless-functions/introduction). This allows page rendering and API requests to scale infinitely.

These optimizations are likely why your page speeds are better with now.sh.

Edit: FYI, ZEIT rebranded to Vercel.